# What does inactive developer path mean in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, xcrun

So I am trying to learn C++ and I am using VS Code as my editor, and when I write my code and attempt to compile in the terminal, I get an error message saying "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun"

What does this mean, and how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you allready ran `xcode-select --install` in Terminal ? This will download and install the Command Line Tools package .

Comment: I did not I am going to do that right now.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Feel free to mark as the answer if so.